# Can Xtext "factorize" features when it generates an Ecore model with multiple inheritance?

Tags: xtext, ecore

If I have the following grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

WithX:
    A | B | C;

A:
    "a" x=INT y=INT;

B:
    "b" x=INT y=INT;

C:
    "c" x=INT;
```

Then Xtext will generate the following Ecore model with a nice super class to factorize `x`:

[image: Ecore model generated from the first grammar]

However, if I add a rule to the grammar to also factorize `y`:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

WithX:
    A | B | C;

WithY:
    A | B ;

A:
    "a" x=INT y=INT;

B:
    "b" x=INT y=INT;

C:
    "c" x=INT;
```

Then the generated Ecore Model does not factorize any feature anymore:

[image: Ecore model generated from the second grammar]

Is there any wait to obtain `x` in `WithX` and `y` in `WithY`?

Answer (score 0):

I just answered my own question. I simply had to add a relationship between `WithX` and `WithY`:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

WithX:
    WithY | C;

WithY:
    A | B ;

A:
    "a" x=INT y=INT;

B:
    "b" x=INT y=INT;

C:
    "c" x=INT;
```

And it now generates:

[image: Ecore model generated from fixed grammar]

Hurray :)